# ImportError: cannot import name 'RedactorTextField'

Tags: python, django

Hey folks here am facing issue while running Django project

1. I installed `Django-WYSIWYG-redactor`
2. added redactor into INSTALLED_APPS = (

   ## ...

   'redactor',

   ## ...

   )
3. Add url(r’^redactor/’, include(‘redactor.urls’)), to urls.py
4. Add default config in settings.py
      # ....
      REDACTOR_OPTIONS = {'lang': 'en'}
      REDACTOR_UPLOAD = 'uploads/'
      # ....
5. In `models.py`

   ```
   from django.db import models
   from redactor.fields import RedactorTextField

   class Entry(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name=u'Title')
     short_text = RedactorTextField(verbose_name=u'Text')
   ```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While I think your post is somewhat understandable, since this is a Q & A site it would be much better if you *ask a question* that can be answered or you may not get answers that are useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field is called `RedactorField`, not `RedactorTextField`. The example from the [pypi page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-wysiwyg-redactor/) is:

```
from redactor.fields import RedactorField

class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name=u'Title')
    short_text = RedactorField(verbose_name=u'Text')
```

Comment: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/app-3.24.0-py3.5.egg/app/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from redactor.fields import RedactorTextField
this file was located in dist-packages

Comment: Thanks for ur reply